# Поиск объекта в лабиринте

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Есть лабиринт в виде матрицы 5*7:

```
1011111
1000001
1110011
1000001
1110111
```

`0` - это проход, `1` - стена;

В лабиринте есть два объекта (`obj1`, `obj2`) которые передвигаются по лабиринту.

Также есть конечная точка (`endPoint`) до которой `obj2` должен добраться.
Известны начальные координаты местоположения обоих объектов, координаты конечной точки, и также известны координаты пути передвижения `obj2`:

```
obj1: 1, 1
obj2: 5, 3
endPoint: 1,3
```

Путь передвижения `obj2`: `4,3; 4,2; 3,2; 3,3; 2,3; 1,3`

Задача следующий: Нужно найти оптимальный путь для `obj2`, при котором `obj2` и `obj1` смогли бы встретится до того как obj1 достигнет конечной точки.

Вопрос: Как можно и как лучше эту задачу реализовать? Мне не нужна полная реализация, нужен только совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно решить с помошью стека

1. создаем копию лабиринта.
   Переходим в начало (вход) лабиринта (4 3)
2. Координаты этого хода записываем в 2 мерный массив (пр. 4 3)
3. Ставим `1` в начало (вход) лабиринта
4. находим куда можно пойти из этой точки

   4 3 4 2

   4 3 4 4

получаем что из (4,3) до (4,2) и (4,4)

5. записываем эти 2 значение в 4 мерный массив (оба в 2 строку)
6. Если нет хода в №5

   - берем последную точку из 2 мерного массива (4 4) (теперь это текушее)
   - Переводим на `0` точку откуда вернулись (4 2)
7. Если есть ход в №5

   - берем последную строку из стека (№5) ( пусть будет 4 3 4 2)
   - удаляем эту строку из стека (№5)
   - переходим в ячейку (4 2) из стека
8. повтор начиная из №2 - (пр 4 2)
9. идем пока не закончится 4мерный стек или не дошли до финиша

Алгоритм работает немного дольше. но для 5*7 быдет оченьб быстро. Проверял на 10*10 в компьюторе IBM 386. работал около 10-15 минут :)

но всегда решение найдеть если даже есть петли